# Creating div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been trying to create a function when button is pressed to create a div inside existing div. That div should be loaded from external source(miniclip.com). I've tried a quite few things and nothing seems to be working. 
I would greatly appreciate any help.
Here is all my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta type="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <script src="https://static.miniclipcdn.com/js/game-embed.js"></script>
<title>Title?</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav>
      <button type="button" id="igra1" class="button1">Opcija 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="igra2" class="button1">Opcija 2</button>
        <button type="button" id="igra3" class="button1">Opcija 3</button>
      </nav>
      </br></br>
      <p style="text-align:center; font-size:55px; color:lightblue;">Za početak odaberi igru</p>
      <div class="baner1">prijmer banera</div></br>
    <div class="content" id="okvir" style="display:none;">
</div>
</br>
       <div class="baner1">prijmer banera</div></br>

      </div>
      <script>
      $('#igra1').click(function()
      {
        $('#okvir').show(1000);
      });
      </script>
      <script>
      $('#igra2').click(function()
      {
        $('#okvir').show(1000);
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class','miniclip-game-embed');
        div.setAttribute('data-game-name', 'basketball-stars');
        div.setAttribute('data-theme','5');
        div.setAttribute('data-width','100%');
        div.setAttribute('data-height', '690px');
        div.setAttribute('data-language','en');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
      });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not quite sure how their embedding of games works, but I assume it looks for an element on the page to insert into. In this case, you need to make sure that the element exists before attempting to load their script. I'd recommend making the request through AJAX **after** you create the element in the click function.

Comment: You can actually look at their code directly. They provide a `build_miniclip_game` function that gets called on window load. Have you tried _calling_ that function?

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: The question is tagged jQuery, so why aren't you using the jQuery functions to create elements and append to the DOM?

Comment: @Barmar I changed that to jquery from javascript after seeing jquery from top to almost bottom. Your question still stands but I need clarification from Azaurus as to whether he was aware of the jQuery functions or if he intends to use plain javascript.

Comment: @Xufox when their code is pasted in normally created div it works just fine. But when I want to create div with JQuery/JS nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can create elements to inside a `div` by appending the new element

```js
      $('#igra1').click(function()
      {
        $('#okvir').show(1000);
      });

      $('#igra2').click(function()
      {
        $('#okvir').show(1000);
        $("#okvir").append("<div style = 'background-color:green;color:white'>NEW DIV</div>");
  
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <nav>
      <button type="button" id="igra1" class="button1">Opcija 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="igra2" class="button1">Opcija 2</button>
        <button type="button" id="igra3" class="button1">Opcija 3</button>
      </nav>
      </br></br>
      <p style="text-align:center; font-size:55px; color:lightblue;">Za početak odaberi igru</p>
      <div class="baner1">prijmer banera</div></br>
    <div class="content" id="okvir" style="display:none;">
    
    </div><!--YOU MISS THE CLOSING div-->
</div>
</br>
       <div class="baner1">prijmer banera</div></br>

      </div>
```

Comment: That really does the job, div is created but I do not get any loading screens

Comment: @Azaurus what do you mean by loading screens?